# Given $x_{1} > 2$ and the recursively defined sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{x_{n}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given $x_{1} > 2$ and the recursively defined sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{x_{n}-1}$.

**Proof:**

(a) $x_{n} \geq 2\ \forall n \geq2$ (which seems obvious given the initial condition, but I also would like some hint to formalize it).

(b) $x_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing.   $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{x_{n}-1}$ = $1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{(x_{n-1}-1)-1}}= 1+\sqrt{\sqrt{x_{n-1}-1}}$ $\dots$
$\sqrt{x_{n-1}-1} = x_{n}-1$ therefore $x_{n-1} > x_{n}$ hence it is decreasing. Is it right?

(c) The limit of this sequence. (It is really where I'm stuck, how do I prove that this sequence is bounded and how to find its limit?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint:* Simplify your task by considering the sequence $y_n = x_n - 1$, which satisfies the recursion $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{y_n}$.

Comment: If you already know that $x_n > 2$ and $(x_n)$ is decreasing then you are almost done!

Comment: Oh, I see! Does it means that the sequence converges to 2, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @VictorHugodaSilvaSouza It means it converges to a limit $L \ge 2$, you still have to prove that $L=2$.

Comment: You posted "Given $x_{1} > 2$ and the recursively defined sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{x_{n}-1}$.

**Proof:**"  Proof of what? What are you going to prove? Please, structure better your question.

Answer (score 1):

You showed that $(x_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence which is lower bounded by $2$, hence $(x_n)_n$ is convergent. To find the limit $l\geq 2$, you can replace $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ by $l$ in your formula : you get
$$l=1+\sqrt{l-1}\Leftrightarrow l^2-2l+1=l-1\Leftrightarrow l^2-3l+2=0,$$
i.e. $l=1$ or $l=2$. Since $l\geq 2$, you get that the sequence converges to $2^+$.

Answer (score 0):

a) We will use induction. The assertion is true for $n=1$, let that it is true for $n=k$, i.e. $x_{k}>2, k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, for $n=k+1$ we gain that $x_{k+1}=1+\sqrt{x_k-1}$ and since $x_k$ is greater than $2$, the assertion is true.
b)We know that $x_n>2\Leftrightarrow x_n-1>1\Rightarrow x_n-1>\sqrt{x_n-1}\Leftrightarrow x_n>1+\sqrt{x_n-1}\Leftrightarrow x_n>x_{n+1}$, I think that this is cleaner.
c) It is already solved above, just take advantage of the fact that $(x_n)_n$ is lower bounded and decreasing and so it has limit, name it $l$ and solve the final equation.

Answer (score 0):

### ad (a)$\def\f#1{{1+\sqrt{{#1}-1}}}$ $\def\ge{\geqslant}$ $\def\le{\leqslant}$

We have $\sqrt x\ge 1$ for all $x\ge1$, thus

$$x_{n+1} - 1 = \sqrt{x_n-1}\geqslant 1$$
under the assumption that $x_n-1\ge 1$.  Induction completes the proof since $x_1 > 2$ (so in particular $x_1\ge 2)$.

### ad (b)

We have $\sqrt x \le x$ for all $x\ge1$, hence
$$x_{n+1} - 1 = \sqrt{x_n-1} \leqslant x_n-1$$
provided $x_n-1\ge1$ which holds due to (a).  It follows immediately that $x_{n+1}\le x_n$ which means $\{x_n\}_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

It's hard to say anything about your computation, I appears some braces are misplaced?

### ad (c)

You already proved the sequence is bounded from below by 2 in (a).  As the sequence of $x_n$ is descreasing, the sequence is convergent.  Moreover, the limit must be 2 at least.

We have an iteration
$$x\mapsto f(x)$$
for the continuous function $f(x) = 1+\sqrt{x-1}$.  If such an iteration converges, then the limit must be a fixed-point of $f$.  More formally, let $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.  Then
$$X = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \text{ exists }\implies X=f(X)$$
Our $f$ has 2 pixed-points, namely $X_1=1$ and $X_2=2$, but we can drop $X_1$ because we know that $X\ge 2$ due to $x_n\ge2$ from (a).

Therefore, we can conclude that the limit of $x_n$ must be $X=2$ without any further computations. If you want some further reasoning on the convergence, what often works is considering $x_n-X$. Here:

$$x_{n+1}-X = f(x_n)-f(X) = (x_n - X)f'(\xi) \quad\text{ with some } \xi\in[X,x_n] $$
due to the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).  As $\xi\ge2$ we have $f'(\xi)\le f'(2)=1/2$ so that

$$\begin{align}
|x_{n+1}-X| &= |x_n - X|\cdot|f'(\xi)|\\
&\le |x_n-X|\frac12 \le |x_1-X|\frac1{2^{n-1}} \\
\end{align}$$
where the last step follows by induction over $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your work seems to rely on “obvious”. However, you're given an exercise and “obvious” should *never* appear in the solution you hand in.

You want/need to use induction.

(a) All terms are greater than $2$. The base step is given, so we go to the induction one. Assuming $x_n>2$, you want to prove that $x_{n+1}>2$ as well. This becomes
$$
1+\sqrt{x_n-1}>2
$$
that holds if and only if
$$
x_n-1>1
$$
which is true by assumption.

However, there is something more to be proved preliminarly, namely that the sequence is well defined: you need to know that $x_n\ge1$ for every $n$, otherwise the sequence would *not* exist to begin with. But this induction is easy: $x_1=2\ge1$; next, if $x_n\ge1$, then $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{x_n-1}\ge1$.

(b) The sequence is monotonically decreasing. This is equivalent to stating that, for every $n$,
$$
x_{n+1}\le x_n
$$
hence that
$$
1+\sqrt{x_n-1}\le x_n
$$
which is the same as
$$
x_n-1\le (x_n-1)^2
$$
hence $x_n^2-3x_n+1\ge0$. This becomes $(x_n-1)(x_n-2)\ge0$, which is true by (a).

(c) The limit $l$ exists because

- statement (a) tells you that the sequence is bounded below and
- statement (b) tells you that the sequence is monotonically decreasing

You also know that $l\ge2$ (a lower bound). Then we have
$$
l=1+\sqrt{l-1}
$$
that becomes, as before,
$$
l^2-3l+2=0
$$
so $l=2$, because the other root is less than $2$.